# Url get redirect in scrapy

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and trying to scrap hotels name for booking.com, just playing. The response URL is different from request URL. I also want to get Hotels names from all pages.

```
    class BookingSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'booking.com_mumbai'
    allowed_domains = ['booking.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaGyIAQGYAS7CAQN4MTHIAQzYAQPoAQGSAgF5qAID&sid=73f533eb666233525bc516654c914549&checkin_month=4&checkin_monthday=26&checkin_year=2017&checkout_month=4&checkout_monthday=30&checkout_year=2017&class_interval=1&dest_id=20014181&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&mih=0&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&raw_dest_type=city&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&search_selected=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&ss=Los%20Angeles%2C%20California%2C%20USA%2C%20North%20America%2C%20CA&ss_all=0&ss_raw=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA%3B&ssb=empty&sshis=0&rows=40&offset=40'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='rows?.\w+', unique=True), follow=True, callback="parse"),
    )

    def parse_hotel_item(self):
        pass

    def parse(self, response):
        hotels = response.xpath('//*[@id="hotellist_inner"]/div')
        for hotel in hotels:
            print hotel.xpath("//h3/a/span[2]/text()").extract()
        print("Done")
```

logs

```
2017-04-15 23:40:48 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: scrap_booking_dot_com)
2017-04-15 23:40:48 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrap_booking_dot_com.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrap_booking_dot_com.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'scrap_booking_dot_com'}
2017-04-15 23:40:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-04-15 23:40:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-04-15 23:40:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-04-15 23:40:48 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-04-15 23:40:48 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-04-15 23:40:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-04-15 23:40:48 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-04-15 23:40:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.booking.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-04-15 23:40:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaGyIAQGYAS7CAQN4MTHIAQzYAQPoAQGSAgF5qAID&sid=73f533eb666233525bc516654c914549&checkin_month=4&checkin_monthday=26&checkin_year=2017&checkout_month=4&checkout_monthday=30&checkout_year=2017&class_interval=1&dest_id=20014181&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&mih=0&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&raw_dest_type=city&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&search_selected=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&ss=Los%20Angeles%2C%20California%2C%20USA%2C%20North%20America%2C%20CA&ss_all=0&ss_raw=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA;&ssb=empty&sshis=0&rows=40&offset=40> from <GET https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaGyIAQGYAS7CAQN4MTHIAQzYAQPoAQGSAgF5qAID&sid=73f533eb666233525bc516654c914549&checkin_month=4&checkin_monthday=26&checkin_year=2017&checkout_month=4&checkout_monthday=30&checkout_year=2017&class_interval=1&dest_id=20014181&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&mih=0&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&raw_dest_type=city&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&search_selected=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&ss=Los%20Angeles%2C%20California%2C%20USA%2C%20North%20America%2C%20CA&ss_all=0&ss_raw=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA%3B&ssb=empty&sshis=0&rows=40&offset=40>
2017-04-15 23:40:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?dest_id=20014181;dest_type=city;offset=30;ss=Los%2520Angeles%252C%2520California%252C%2520USA%252C%2520North%2520America%252C%2520CA> from <GET https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaGyIAQGYAS7CAQN4MTHIAQzYAQPoAQGSAgF5qAID&sid=73f533eb666233525bc516654c914549&checkin_month=4&checkin_monthday=26&checkin_year=2017&checkout_month=4&checkout_monthday=30&checkout_year=2017&class_interval=1&dest_id=20014181&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&mih=0&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&raw_dest_type=city&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&search_selected=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&ss=Los%20Angeles%2C%20California%2C%20USA%2C%20North%20America%2C%20CA&ss_all=0&ss_raw=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA;&ssb=empty&sshis=0&rows=40&offset=40>
2017-04-15 23:40:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?dest_id=20014181;dest_type=city;offset=30;ss=Los%20Angeles%2C%20California%2C%20USA%2C%20North%20America%2C%20CA> from <GET https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?dest_id=20014181;dest_type=city;offset=30;ss=Los%2520Angeles%252C%2520California%252C%2520USA%252C%2520North%2520America%252C%2520CA>
2017-04-15 23:40:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?dest_id=20014181;dest_type=city;offset=30;ss=Los%20Angeles%2C%20California%2C%20USA%2C%20North%20America%2C%20CA> (referer: None)
```

I am getting different results.

Comment: What results are you getting? Post your scrapy logs as well

Comment: You need to remove `allowed_domains = ['booking.com']` if you want to scrape pages outside `booking.com`

Comment: @Umair i added logs

Answer (score 0):

According to your logs and source code your scraper is starting at

https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?dest_id=20014181;dest_type=city;offset=30;ss=Los%20Angeles%2C%20California%2C%20USA%2C%20North%20America%2C%20CA

and then is redirected multiple times so it ends up scraping

https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaGyIAQGYAS7CAQN4MTHIAQzYAQPoAQGSAgF5qAID&sid=73f533eb666233525bc516654c914549&checkin_month=4&checkin_monthday=26&checkin_year=2017&checkout_month=4&checkout_monthday=30&checkout_year=2017&class_interval=1&dest_id=20014181&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&mih=0&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&raw_dest_type=city&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&search_selected=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&ss=Los%20Angeles%2C%20California%2C%20USA%2C%20North%20America%2C%20CA&ss_all=0&ss_raw=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA%3B&ssb=empty&sshis=0&rows=40&offset=40

**And there is nothing wrong with this.**

Why?

That's the way booking.com handles your start url. It's nothing special happening to your scraper, the same happens when trying to access the start url in a browser.

Just paste your start url into a browser and you will see the browser's URL line change to an almost identical long URL.

So the response url is fine.

**The real problem** comes from the xpath `"//h3/a/span[2]/text()"` in the for loop.

There are two problems with it:

1. as the xpath starts with '/' it will work on the root object while you most probably want it to work on each of the hotel elements that you are iterating over.

The fix is to add a '.' to the front of the xpath (similar to using a '.' when navigating folders on a file system).

Example: `".//h3/a/span[2]/text()"`

2. Nonetheless I couldn't make your xpath work. Crafted the following xpath instead which works fine for me: `".//span[@class='sr-hotel__name']/text()"`

(a good xpath should rely preferable on ids and class names, instead of a particular nesting of elements, as the former are less at risk to change)